# configure temporary account lockout using powershell

Tags: windows-8.1, security, powershell, gpedit

My Windows 8.1 laptop does not have gpedit.msc.  I want to configure my laptop so that the account is locked for 15 mins if anyone enters the wrong password three times.

I have found some web pages with links to install gpedit, but I am not sure I can trust the source of the download.

Is there a way to accomplish this without gpedit using a powershell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky because those settings are stored in the SAM part of the registry which is not easily available to a script or users, the settings are in binary format in

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM\SAM\Domains\Account\F]
```

One way to change this is to create a text file like C:\NewLockoutSettings.txt with this content:

```
 [Unicode]
 Unicode=yes
 [Version]
 signature="$CHICAGO$"
 Revision=1
 [System Access]
 LockoutBadCount = 3
 ResetLockoutCount = 15
 LockoutDuration = 15
```

Then use the file as the input for secedit.exe like this:

```
 secedit.exe /configure /db "secedit.sdb" /cfg C:\NewLockoutSettings.txt
```

The text file is called a security template and you apply it against the standard security database.

Of course you have to run this as an elevated administrator, and I would test this on a VM before applying it on a production machine.

Comment: Impressive hack, I think I might stick with gpedit.msc I might be able to get gpedit.msc off of a friends computer.